# Pandas not recognizing Excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am wanting to readability analysis with text data stored in an Excel file.  Part of the code I have adapted is below:

```
import time, datetime     
import pandas as pd     
from textstat.textstat import textstat    
from openpyxl import load_workbook    

ExcelFile = 'Readability.xlsx'
Sheet = 'Raw Data'
Field_ID = 0 

book = load_workbook(ExcelFile)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(ExcelFile, engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
df = pd.read_excel(ExcelFile, sheet_name=Sheet)
```

I get the following error after running:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\file\UsersR$\rtf13\Home\Desktop\readability_using_textstat.py", line 19, in <module>
    df = pd.read_excel(ExcelFile, sheet_name=Sheet)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 336, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1071, in __init__
    ext = inspect_excel_format(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 965, in inspect_excel_format
    raise ValueError("File is not a recognized excel file")
ValueError: File is not a recognized excel file
```

Also, the Excel file ends up corrupted after running the code. I am using pandas 1.2.4, openpyxl 3.0.7 and used xlrd 1.2.0 (because of later versions not working with .xlsx files).  Any advice welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.ExcelWriter` is used for writing `pd.DataFrame`Objets.

```
df = pd.read_excel(ExcelFile) 
with ExcelWriter(ExcelFile , mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=Sheet)
```

---

## Update

Try it like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'<path_to_file>\Readability.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') # UPDATED: pip install openpyxl

with ExcelWriter(ExcelFile , mode='a') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=Sheet)
```

Check more at [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html)

Comment: Thanks @Anurag Dhadse. I tried this but still get the identical error message, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Anurag Dhadse. Adding _mode='a'_ to the _writer=_ line in the original code worked, i.e., `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(ExcelFile, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')`

Comment: @RFCHCH Please upvote and accept if the answer helped :)